# Index used, other field in query gets ignored

Tags: arangodb

I have a non unique non sparse hash index on a collection "coll2" on fields "a,b[*]". When I query this collection in a subquery:

```
    FOR r IN coll
      RETURN COUNT(
        FOR rr IN coll2 
          FILTER rr.a == true &&
                 r.id IN rr.b &&
                 r.id IN rr.c 
          RETURN null
    )
```

I get a result as if the filter on field c is ignored. Explaining the query confirms that my hash index is used. If I create another non unique non sparse hash index on fields "a,b[*],c[*]", then the result is as expected and explaining the query confirms that my new index is used.

I can confirm that it doesn't do that when directly querying coll2, even with a two fields index. Explaining the query shows that in this case it will use the two fields index and then create a filter as a simple expression for the field that is not in the index. Is it a bug?

Comment: Would you please print the output of the query optimizer (`Explain` button on UI instead of `Execute`)

Comment: It was a bug. Thanks for trying to help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug. Here's the reference on github https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/4900